# Почему массив неправильно сортируется методом пузырька?

Tags: c, сортировка, c++

В чем ошибка?

```
for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6 - k; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
            z = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может быть, вы ему подаёте массив не той длины?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка? Сортирует же!
http://codepad.org/ua7k5RNC

Answer (score 0):

Второй цикл должен быть вот таким:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6 - k - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если длина данного массива равна шести элементам, то попробуйте изменить внешний цикл на

```
for (k = 1; k < 6 - 1; k++)
```

Comment: Ой, я тупой. Не заметил, что массив сортируется по убыванию.

Answer (score 0):

Для ускорения работы можно попробовать зеркально отобразить метод пузырька для упорядочения массива по возрастанию.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i, k, z;
    int a[6] = { 4, 3, 6, 8, 3, 10 };

    for (k = 0; k < 6 - 1; k++) {
        for (i = 6 - 1; i > k; i--) {
            if (a[i - 1] < a[i]) {
                z = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i - 1];
                a[i - 1] = z;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << ", ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Для ПУЗЫРЬКОВОЙ сортировки на КАЖДОМ проходе сканировать массив опять с самого НАЧАЛА

```
for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6 - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i + 1]) {
            z = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = z;
        }
    }
}
```

При данной реализации будет все 6 проходов, даже если после 3 проходов массив уже отсортирован. Можно включить проверку на отсортированность